# Get specific div from a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

On my admin panel I have a page called "Les Vétérans".
In this page I wrote some content into a custom div called "description" on the WYSIWYG.

Now in my php code, I want to display this div without using `the_content();`
I just want to target and display only this div and not the rest (there is more content on this page).

Comment: can't you do it with jQuery ? on document.ready ? Maybe the problem is not to show "just one `div`", but you should maybe put this `div` in a separate file, and call at different places (it looks like you want to display it in 2 different pages ?) ?

Comment: Well in my case I will have multiple divs, their class will be the same. So I want to display them on my php page. Below each div I want to display a different description for each. So I will foreach my divs and for each div display their description

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure to get the point. Can you give a an explicit exemple please ? (what the `Veterans page` looks like, what are the data you want to use, and what exactly you want to do from it ?

Comment: Veterans page show 5 persons with their picture, name and description. For each person I have a caption and a shortcode where you can write text in it. In my code, for each person I want to display their caption + the shortcode taken from the wordpress editor. And I don't want to use the function the_content();

Comment: can you edit your question, showing piece of php and/or html code ?

Comment: Here's a picture from my editor http://imgur.com/pF0Pk3a

Comment: have you tried @AryehArmon's answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content and then with a regular expression get tge part that you want.

Here is example code:

```
$content = get_the_content();

if (preg_match('/<div id="mydiv">([^<]*)<\/div>/', $content, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches[1]; //This is my div
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I'm trying to display two divs called <div id="description">Test</div> Like this http://imgur.com/hvODvan and http://imgur.com/f0IzAPV